# Open files in MS-Office client app on Mac rather than download to local drive

Tags: download

When I email/send URL links to documents to Mac users such as

http://sharepointsitedomain.com/Projects/sitename/Shared%20Documents/data.xls

and the user clicks on the link the file is downloaded to the local drive.
From wich the user can open it. They are now working on the local copy not the centrally managed document.

But On windows it actually opens up in Excel and the user can then Check out the file and work on it, Check it in etc.

How can I configure a Mac and Sharepoint so that referenec files are opened in the client app.  I would have thought that I'd be able to specifiy the MIME application in the browser but my Mac guy does not seem to think that this will help.

Any thoughts on how I can get a Mac to open files in SharePoint.

Answer (score 4):

Best case scenario is to get your Mac users comfortable with the Office Document Connection application.  It allows for checking in and out of the files and working off the server documents.

Comment: + 1 to me this is the best way

Answer (score 2):

Check my step-by-step post: [Working with document stored in SharePoint site using Document Connection](http://thuansoldier.net/?p=2173)

You will learn about how to:

- Connect to a SharePoint site using Document Connection
- Upload document into a document library
- Check-Out/Check-In/Discard a document

Comment: Voted up but (as you note) there are limitations. The inability of Microsoft Document Connection to copy or move a folder from OS X may be most disappointing to users who are accustomed to working with folders, so I'd prefer file system integration.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure … Sharepoint …

If you can configure SharePoint to allow ._ (dot underbar) and other file names beginning with . then SharePoint may offer a more integrated service.

(File system integration – SharePoint as a volume – is not a feature of Microsoft Document Connection.)

---

In Ask Different: [Is it possible to mount SharePoint as a volume in 10.6?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7030/8546)

Some answers to that questions are not specific to Snow Leopard:

- [System-managed WebDAV connections to SharePoint](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49663/8546)
- [Transmit WebDAV HTTPS connection to SharePoint](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51148/8546)
- [wdfs (with FUSE) for a WebDAV connection to SharePoint](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50012/8546)

Of those three: system-managed connections should be ideal, but Microsoft's design of SharePoint (the file name restrictions) makes the service **not** work with file system integration for Microsoft Office apps. So begin by easing the restrictions in SharePoint.